# Confusion on proofing Noether's theorem in field theory

Tags: symmetry, field-theory, variational-principle, noethers-theorem, classical-field-theory

I've been following along Gleb Arutyunov and Henk Stoof's Classical Field Theory lecture notes. It basically want to proof the Noether's theorem in field theory by considering an infinitesimal transformation:

\begin{equation}
x^i \rightarrow x'^i=x^i+\delta x^i, \qquad i=1,...,d,\\
\phi_I(x) \rightarrow \phi'_I(x')=\phi_I(x) +\delta\phi_I(x).
\end{equation}
with the variation $\delta x^i$ and $\delta \phi_I$ are expressed via infinitesimal linearly-independent parameters $\delta\omega_n$:
\begin{equation}
\delta x^i = \sum_{1 \leq n\leq s} X^i_n \delta \omega_n , \qquad \delta \phi_I(x)= \sum_{1 \leq n\leq s} \Phi_{I,n}\delta \omega_n. \qquad (1)
\end{equation}
Here all $\delta\omega_n$ are independent of coordinates x. The coefficient $X^i_n$ and $\Phi_{I,n}$ may depend on $x$ and the fields, and they describe a response of coordinates and field on the infiniitesimal transformation with a parameter $\delta \omega_n$.

In the general case of symmetry transformations:
\begin{aligned}
\phi'_I(x')&=\phi'(x+\delta x) \\
&=\phi'_I(x)+\partial_k\phi'_I(x)\delta x^k+... &&(2)\\
&=\phi'_I(x)+\partial_k\phi_I(x)X^k_n\delta\omega_n +... &&(3)
\end{aligned}

It is important to realize that the operations $\delta$ and $\partial/\partial x$ do not commute. We therefore introduce the notion of variation of the form of the field function

\begin{aligned}
\overline{\delta}\phi_I(x)&=\phi'_I(x)-\phi_I(x) &&(4)\\ &=(\Phi_{I,n}-\partial_k\phi_I X^k_n)\delta \omega_n &&(5)
\end{aligned}

Based on these, I have four questions:

1. In (1), how do we know that the variations $\delta x^i$ and $\delta \phi_I$ can be expressed via the same infinitesimal linearly-independent parameters $\delta\omega_n$? Is there a reason why we can't use two different parameters?
2. In (2) to (3), why $\phi'_I(x)$ change into $\phi'_I(x)$?
3. Why $\delta$ and $\partial/\partial x$ does not commute?
4. I can't see why (4) is the same as (5)

Any answers to any of my questions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. $\delta\omega_n$ are the parameters of your variation. $\delta x$ and $\delta \phi$ are the quantities that change **due** to these variations. You can think of these $\delta \omega$ as physical causes of change. You could use different parameters for field and coordinate but it would not be very physically clear. Here, equation (1) really tells us, what changes due to what variation and these **linearly independent** $\delta \omega$ are all we need **at first order**.
   Take for example a spacetime shift. You'll change each coordinate by $a$ so $\delta \omega = a$ and $X^i = 1$. You'll also ask for the fields to not change under this transformation (after both a coordinate and field change at fixed coordinate): $\delta \phi = 0\Rightarrow \Phi = 0$.
2. $\phi'(x) - \phi(x)$ is of order $\delta \omega$ and $\delta x$ so the difference between $\partial_k\phi'_I(x)\delta x^k$ and $\partial_k\phi_I(x)\delta x^k$ is of order $\delta \omega\delta x$ and $\delta x^2$. We get rid of it since we keep only first order terms.
   *EDIT:* To be a bit more explicit. Starting from your first equation at the very top of your post: $\phi'_I(x + \delta x)=\phi_I(x) +\delta\phi_I(x)\Rightarrow\phi'_I(x) + \underbrace{(\partial_{k}\phi_I'(x))\delta x^k}_{\textrm{order } \delta x}=\phi_I(x) +\underbrace{\delta\phi_I(x)}_{\textrm{order } \delta w}$. From this you see that $\phi(x)$ and $\phi'(x)$ differ by term of order $\delta x$ and $\delta w$. So, if we want to be explicit:
   $$\partial_k\phi'_I(x)\delta x^k = \partial_k(\phi_I(x) + \delta \phi_I(x) + \partial_j\phi_I(x)\delta x^j)\delta x^k = \partial_k(\phi_I(x))\delta x^k + O((\delta x)^2) + O(\delta w\delta x)$$We only keep the first order term to get to the wanted result!
3. We have clearly $\partial (\delta \phi) = \sum (\partial_x \Phi(x))\omega$ but it's not very clear how to get $\delta (\partial \phi) $ to compare it with the first expression since the derivative might act on $x$ or on $x'$. For example it doesn't work with these definitions: $$\delta (\partial \phi)\equiv\partial_x(\phi'(x') - \phi(x))=\partial_x(\phi'(x + \delta x)) - \partial_x(\phi(x)) \neq \partial (\delta \phi) $$ or $$\delta (\partial \phi)\equiv\partial_{x'}(\phi'(x')) - \partial_x(\phi(x))\neq \partial (\delta \phi) $$ These two expression won't be equal to $\partial(\delta\phi)$ because terms in $\partial_xX(x)$ will appear which are not present in $\sum (\partial_x \Phi(x))\omega$.
4. We start from $$\overline{\delta}\phi(x)=\phi'(x)-\phi(x).$$ Thanks to Eq. (3) we can rewrite $\phi'(x)$:
   $$\begin{aligned}\overline{\delta}\phi(x)&=(\phi'(x')-\partial_k\phi X_k \delta \omega) -\phi(x)\\ &=\delta\phi - \partial_k\phi X_k \delta \omega\end{aligned}$$
   Then using Eq. (1) to rewrite $\delta \phi$ we get to the wanted result (note the implicit sum in Eq. (5).

Comment: Can you elaborate more on why difference between $\phi '_I$ and $\phi_I$ is of order $\delta \omega$ ? Is it due to the $\phi '_I$ is a transformed version of $\phi_I$?

Comment: @Andrijauhari I updated the bullet point 2.